# Navegadores e ES6

Tags: javascript, front-end, ecmascript-6

Estou começando os estudos em ES6 e meu curso é de 2018, gostaria de saber se os navegadores já suportam a tecnologia ou ainda é necessária a utilização dos compiladores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maioria dos navegadores modernos já suportam o ECMAScript 2015 (vulgo ES6) nativamente, além das versões posteriores. No entanto, não há como garantir que todos os seus usuários sempre usarão navegadores que suportem esse tipo de recurso mais novo.

Portanto, é sempre ideal que você sirva um código JavaScript que, no mínimo, consiga ser suportado pelos browsers mais usados (o que inclui alguns antigos, como o IE 11, que ainda são <s>infelizmente</s> usados por muitas pessoas).

Assim, se você estiver programando para a web, é quase sempre escrever o código JavaScript usando somente recursos anteriores ao ES6, isso é, ES5 ou antes. No caso de você usar recursos mais modernos, pode usar transpiladores como o Babel.

Para saber mais sobre a compatibilidade, veja [esta tabela de compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/#search=es6).